# Error: "In included file: 'avr/pgmspace.h' file not found (clang pp_file_not_found)" on Neovim with Coc

Tags: c++, c, arduino, clang, neovim

I'm trying to add code completion to my Neovim to program some stuff with [Platform.io](https://platformio.org) but clang doesn't recognize the `Arduino.h` import and blames the `avr/pgmspace.h` header.

[image: In included file: 'avr/pgmspace.h' file not found (clang pp_file_not_found)]

- The plugin I'm using is [Conqueror of Completion](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim)
- I have `coc-clang` installed
- My `CocConfig` file is empty, I also tried ccls but no luck.
- My [Vim-Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) extensions

```
- neomake-platformio: OK
- coc.nvim: OK
- vim-pio: OK
- fzf.vim: OK
- fzf: OK
```

- My `platformio.ini`

```
; bla bla bla comments
[env:uno]
platform = atmelavr
board = uno
framework = arduino
```

- My `compile_commands.json` created via `pio run -t compiledb` (also tried [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) and it didn't work)

```
[
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/CDC.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/CDC.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/CDC.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial0.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial0.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial1.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial1.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial2.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial2.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial3.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial3.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/IPAddress.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/IPAddress.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/IPAddress.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/PluggableUSB.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/PluggableUSB.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/PluggableUSB.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/Print.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/Print.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/Print.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/Stream.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/Stream.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/Stream.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/Tone.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/USBCore.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-gcc -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/WInterrupts.c.o -c -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.c",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.c"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/WMath.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/WString.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/WString.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/WString.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/abi.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/abi.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/abi.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-gcc -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/hooks.c.o -c -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/hooks.c",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/hooks.c"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/main.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/main.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/main.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/new.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/new.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/new.cpp"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-gcc -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/wiring.c.o -c -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-gcc -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/wiring_analog.c.o -c -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-gcc -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/wiring_digital.c.o -c -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-as -mmcu=atmega328p -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/wiring_pulse.S.o /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.S",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.S"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-gcc -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/wiring_pulse.c.o -c -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.c",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.c"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-gcc -o .pio/build/uno/FrameworkArduino/wiring_shift.c.o -c -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring_shift.c",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino/wiring_shift.c"
    },
    {
        "command": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/avr-g++ -o .pio/build/uno/src/main.cpp.o -c -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -DPLATFORMIO=60106 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO=10808 -Iinclude -Isrc -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/cores/arduino -I/Users/MY_USER_NAME/.platformio/packages/framework-arduino-avr/variants/standard src/main.cpp",
        "directory": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD",
        "file": "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Projects/PIO_LCD/src/main.cpp"
    }
]
```

If there are any other information that you guys find that might be useful, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 3 problems:

1. as a package manager I was using [MacPorts](https://macports.org), even though you ask it to install ccls via `sudo port install ccls` it installs it as `ccls-clang-10`, so the completion engine does not recognize the ccls command.
2. I didn't follow the instructions the [ccls repo provides](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls/wiki/Build#macos), especially the one that tells you to create a shell wrapper, when you use MacPorts, it's a must (or you could just change the command as you will see in the next problem)
3. I was using [coc.nvim's configuration](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Language-servers#ccobjective-c) and it just didn't work, after search a little I found that the [ccls repo provides a config JSON for coc.nvim](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls/wiki/coc.nvim), when I used it BAM it was working! Also, as I stated above, look to see if the `"command": "ccls"` fits the one you have, maybe I could just used it as `ccls-clang-10` and it would've worked.

I hope you find this useful, if you come across this.